# Does a cube of force's button 4 effect protect those inside it from spells cast inside it?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

A PC activated a *cube of force*, pressing button 4 so that "Spell effects can't pass through the barrier." Then, an enemy archmage enters the *cube* effect and tries to cast *banishment* on the PC.

What happens? Does the spell fail? Is the PC affected normally? Something else?

Comment: I don't  get what   you are talking  about "button 4".

Comment: If you read the ability's on cube of force it has this effect when pressed Spell effects can 't pass through the barrier.

Comment: You might want to add a quote saying what button 4 does from the Cube of Force entry in the DMG; off the top of my head I can't remember what the buttons do... EDIT: I posted seconds after you comment and didn't see it, but including a DMG quote would still help your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Cube of Force(option 4) does not stop Banishment.

snippets of Cube of Force

> Each face has a different effect....a barrier of Invisible force springs into existence, forming a cube 15 feet on a side. The barrier is centered on you, moves with you, and lasts for 1 minute.... 
> face - charges
> 4 — 4 — Spell effects can 't pass through the barrier.

Nothing in the item's description implies that spells can't be cast from within the cube (compared to [AntiMagic Field](http://engl393-dnd5th.wikia.com/wiki/Antimagic_Field)). [Banishment](http://engl393-dnd5th.wikia.com/wiki/Banishment) doesn't "send out" an effect, so there's no reason that the two should interact.

The archmagi would walk in and cast Banishment. Pending a failed save, the player who initiated the Cube of Force would blink out of existence, along with their cube effect. Then 1 minute later, they would reappear, without the cubes effect, as more than 1 minute has passed since the Cube of Force was activated.

<sup>PS - Though this doesn't apply to this exact interaction, I'm not sure if you could teleport from inside of the cube to outside or vice versa (think Dimension Door). My inclination is to say, that you could, as you're bypassing the barrier. Much as if it were a physical wall. Wizards can't walk through walls, but they can teleport to the other side.</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure if OP intended it, but the wording of "spell effects" is an unusual one. It is not explicitly talking about targeting. For instance would teleporting to inside (or from inside to outside) the cube count? A reasonable reading of the word "effect" might suggest that transportation effects that moved things in or out of the cube would be prevented . . .

Comment: @NeilSlater I agree that it COULD prevent things from being moved inside of or outside of the cube. But in this particular case, you're moving the operator, thus the cube, as well.

I'm much less certain RAW/RAI of Dimension Door being used from the inside of the cube to outside or vice versa.

Comment: The arch-magi may be at a significant disadvantage having lost any spell effects active on his person on the way into the cube